# Adding something in the database(mysql / phpmyadmin) with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, sublimetext2

i'm making a website. It has a login form, that transfer to the admin section when you're logged in. It works perfectly, it searches everything in the database, it's everything ok. But the register link isn't working properly. The `cadastro.php` file should do the register to the `cadastra_usuario.php` and transfer right to the login page if everything went ok. It also should bring a warning if the password don't match or if some space are missing. It doesn't even register in the database and don't do nothing of this. Here's the codes:

The include's and the form of `cadastro.php`:

```
<body>
    <div class="container container-twelve">
        <div class="four columns offset-by-four">
            <h1 class="titles">Cadastro</h1>
            <?php if(isset($_SESSION["success"])) {?>
            <p><?= $_SESSION["success"] ?></p>
        <?php }?>
        <?php unset($_SESSION["success"]); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="four columns offset-by-four" id ="login">
            <form action="cadastra_usuario.php"  method="post">
                <label for="nome">Nome</label>
                <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Digite seu nome">
                <label for="email">Email de usuário </label>
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Seu email para login">
                <label for="senha">Senha</label>
                <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Sua senha">
                <label for="senha2">Repita sua senha</label>
                <input type="password" name="senha2" placeholder="Repita sua senha">
                <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
            </form>

            <p><a href="index.php"> << Voltar para o site</a></p>
            <p><a href="login.php"> Já tenho um cadastro >> </a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

cadastra_usuario.php:
<?php 
    include('conecta.php');
    include('functions.php');
    include('function_usuario.php');

    $senha = $_POST['senha'];
    $senha2 = $_POST['senha2'];

    $cadastra = cadastraUsuario();

    if($senha != $senha2){
        $_SESSION["danger"] = "As senhas não conferem!";
        header("Location: cadastro.php");
    }
    if($cadastra == null){
        $_SESSION["danger"] = "Complete todos os campos!";
        header("Location: cadastro.php");
    } else {
        $_SESSION["success"] = "Usuário cadastrado com sucesso.";
        header("Location: login.php");
    }
?>
```

and the function:

```
function cadastraUsuario($conexao, $nome, $email, $senha){
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $senha = $_POST['senha'];

    $conexao = mysqli_connect('mysql.hostinger.com.br','u374984363_ozzy','ozzy@123', 'u374984363_ncars');
    $query = "insert into usuarios (nome, email, senha) values ('{$nome}', '{$email}', '{$senha}')";
    return mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hard to tell, but:

```
function cadastraUsuario($conexao, $nome, $email, $senha)
```

awaits $conexao which should be the DB connection, right? But when you call the function, you are not giving the connection:

```
$cadastra = cadastraUsuario($_POST['nome'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['senha']);
```

This won't work.

Maybe this a solution:

```
function cadastraUsuario($nome, $email, $senha) {
    $query = "insert into usuarios (nome, email, senha) values ('{$nome}', '{$email}', '{$senha}')";

    $mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");

    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }

    if (!$mysqli->query($query)) {
        echo "Insert failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
    }
}
```

Some advices from a developer:

- Never write $_POST variables directly to the DB. This allows SQL injection aka security issue!
- Write a log function and do application logs as much as possible
- Check phperror.log for error if you encounter an error

Comment: alright, thx for the help man ! But the $conexao is a class that conect to the database, everything else works just like that... 'bout the $_POST in the DB, i didn't knew it, thanks a lot ! And btw... it didn't worked at all, the strange thing is that it doesn't even show me an error if i click the button with all blank,,,

Comment: you should check phperror.log or enable if not available configure error logging of PHP. Or just enable display errors: http://php.net/manual/de/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors Concerning $conexao: This is not class but an object. But this is not important, because you haven't passed it. So this can't work. You properly get a PHP Fatal Error. That why you get the blank page. The reason for the Fatal Error is the wrong count of parameters of function cadastraUsuario()

Comment: So if you have a instance of the DB connetion in $conexao, just pass it: cadastraUsuario($conexao, $_POST['nome'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['senha']);

Comment: ok, just solved the problem now ! Updated the function and it worked alright ! Thanks !